# Any unix wizardy to mount a device in the bare metal OS from a container

Tags: docker, containers

We use containers to provision storage on our storage nodes but I can't for the life of my figure out a way to mount a device to the bare metal OS from a container. Both bare metal and containers are running oracle linux 7.5.

We *cannot* use ssh in any form for this. This is an isolated compute environment and the only access is thru the orchestration we use to manage containers.

I'm mainly a solaris guy so wondering if there is any linux magic I can work here.

I can mount any bare metal devices or filesystems into the container and I can run the container in privileged more.

Thx for any help

*** clarification ***

This is *not* about mounting a volume into a container.

This container is a temporary provisioning container, ie: it does stuff like mount iscisi volumes, create volume groups, create logical volumes and make filesystems.

This part is all working fine.

The last step this container needs to do is somehow tell the BARE METAL OPERATING SYSTEM TO MOUNT A DEVICE INTO IT'S FILESYSTEM. NOT IN THE CONTAINER.

Simplistic example: I need this container to somehow tell the OS to "mount /dev/sdg /data".

This mount does not need to be available to the container. The container is being destroyed once it allocate the storage and mounts it.

And we can't use SSH for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems you need to overcome.

1. By default, Docker does not have access to block devices on the
   host.
2. A docker container is unable to modify its own mount namespace.
3. A docker container runs in a private mount namespace, so even after
   solving (1) and (2), any mounts you make inside the container will
   not be visible from the host.

Fortunately, there are solutions to all of the above!

We can solve (1) and (2) by passing the `--privileged` flag to
`docker run`. This removes all the restrictions that Docker normally
places on a container.

For solving (3), we need to use the `--mount` option instead of the
`-v` option, since we need to modify the style of mount propagation
used.  Reading through the [documentation on
bind-mounts](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/),
we see that the `--mount` option supports the following options:

> - The type of the mount, which can be bind, volume, or tmpfs. This topic discusses bind mounts, so the type will always be bind.
> - The source of the mount. For bind mounts, this is the path to the file or directory on the Docker daemon host. May be specified as source or src.
> - The destination takes as its value the path where the file or directory will be mounted in the container. May be specified as destination, dst, or target.
> - The readonly option, if present, causes the bind mount to be mounted into the container as read-only.
> - The bind-propagation option, if present, changes the bind propagation. May be one of rprivate, private, rshared, shared, rslave, slave.
> - The consistency option, if present, may be one of consistent, delegated, or cached. This setting only applies to Docker for Mac, and is ignored on all other platforms.

The one we care about is the `bind-propagation` option.  The values for
that are described [later on in the same
document](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation).
Reading through them, we probably want `rshared`.

Armed with this knowledge, I can run:

```
docker run -it \
  --mount type=bind,source=/,dst=/host,bind-propagation=rshared \
  --privileged alpine sh
```

Then inside the container I can run, for example:

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /host/mnt
```

And on the host I see the contents of `/dev/sdd1` mounted on `/mnt`. The mount will persist after the container exits.

Comment: I'm running 18.06 and I have it (`docker run --help | grep mount`).

Comment: Yea turns out this node was running 17.0.3 non ce version and for some reason it had no --mount option.

Comment: Yea this helped but I also ended up having to monkey around with lvm.conf and disable some udev related things, otherwise it wouldn't mount the filesystem at the baremetal level. I ended up abandoning this approach and am writing a lowel-level go tool to create volumes directly.